# Method overloading in Java: The method is not applicable for arguments

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to use predicates, but I can't because method overloading is acting up...

I want to use *filter* with an array (varargs), and I want to use the built-in method in predicates, that filters the array as converted to a list.

This is the error: *The method filter(Iterable, Predicate) in the type Predicates is not applicable for the arguments (Class[], Predicate)*

```
private static final Predicate<Method> isTestMethod = new Predicate<Method>() {
    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(Method input) {
        return input.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class);
    }
};

public static void testClasses(Class<?>... classes) {
    for (Method method : filter(classes, isTestMethod)) {

    }
}
```

This is the predicates methods:

```
/**
 * Returns the elements of <tt>unfiltered</tt> that satisfy a predicate.
 * 
 * @param unfiltered An iterable containing objects of any type
 * that will be filtered and used as the result.
 * @param predicate The predicate to use for evaluation.
 * @return An iterable containing all objects which passed the predicate's evaluation.
 */
public static <T> Iterable<T> filter(Iterable<T> unfiltered, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    checkNotNull(unfiltered);
    checkNotNull(predicate);

    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    Iterator<T> iterator = unfiltered.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        T next = iterator.next();
        if (predicate.evaluate(next)) {
            result.add(next);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Returns the elements of <tt>unfiltered</tt> that satisfy a predicate.
 * 
 * @param unfiltered An array containing objects of any type
 * that will be filtered and used as the result.
 * @param predicate The predicate to use for evaluation.
 * @return An iterable containing all objects which passed the predicate's evaluation.
 */
public static <T> Iterable<T> filter(T[] unfiltered, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return filter(Arrays.asList(unfiltered), predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your filter is applicable to *methods* - but you have a collection of *classes*. You can't apply your `isTestMethod` predicate to a class...

What did you anticipate it would do? Were you perhaps looking for a filter to match classes which had *any* test methods?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. I am an idiot.

```
    for (Class<?> testClass : classes) {
        for (Method method : filter(testClass.getClass().getMethods(), isTestMethod)) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: `classes.getClass()` will return the `Class` representing the class of the array.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on drugs (cough medicine), haha.